# Why does $\Sigma=\{A:|A|<\infty\;\text{or}\,|A^c|<\infty\}$ not a sigma-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I don't see too much difference between this two sets

**1.** $$\Sigma=\{A:|A|<\infty\;\text{or}\,|A^c|<\infty\}$$

**2** $$\Sigma=\{A:\text{either}\,A\,\text{or}\,A^c\,\text{is finite or countable}\}$$

Why does the first one is not a sigma-algebra, but the second one is?

**My attempt:** I can prove $\emptyset,\Omega\in\Sigma$ for both cases, and they are both closed under complement.  Whenever $A\in\Sigma,A=(A^c)^c\in\Sigma$. I think the only differences only occur for closed under countable union, but I cannot go further.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If support set is finite, then it **is** a $\sigma$-algebra.

Otherwise, assume $x_i$, $i \in \mathbb N$ are different elements of support.

Take $A_i = \{x_{2i}\}$. Then each $A_i \in \Sigma$, but $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \notin \Sigma$ because $A$ is infinite and also $A^c$ contains infinite set $\{x_{2i + 1} | i \in \mathbb N\}$, so it's infinite too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean $\Omega$ support set? Do you mean each $A_i$ is countable infinite, then it's countable union is not in $\Sigma$. If each $A_i$ is countable infinite, then their corresponing $A^c$ will be finite, then $\bigcap_i A^c_i$ is finite, so I think it should in $\Sigma$?

Comment: Yes, support set is another name for $\Omega$ in definiton of $\sigma$-algebra. Each $A_i$ is finite (and has only 1 element), as defined. I don't consider anything about complement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't see why $\bigcup^\infty_{i=1} A_i\notin\Sigma$, such thing is infinite I agree, but what if it's complement is finite, then it could in $\Sigma$

Comment: Because it's complement is at least $\{x_{2i + 1} | i \in \mathbb N\}$, which is infinite.

Comment: @LJNG Just take $\Omega=\Bbb{N}$ and take the union of all the odd numbers(singletons like $\{1\}\cup\{3\}\cup....$ That is a countable union . But it cannot be in $\Sigma$ because it is infinite and it's complement is the set of even numbers which is also infinite.